# Which one should I use? Post, Send, Share, Okay, Apply

Tags: interface, user-expectation

Many action verbs have been used for confirmation or to pass information from one place to another especially for a social or forum-like website or app that people have options to comment.

So my question is this: **Which is best to use on a forum or social site for users to commit the message they have typed in a comment box for other forum users to see  Post, share , send , okay or apply?**

EDIT: Also any usability study on this will be super helpful too

Answer (score 2):

Best is something that makes completely clear what happens when you press the button.

It is good pratice to appoint the action and the subject while keeping it concise. A good example is right on this page: **"Post Your Answer"** is used instead of just **"Post"**. If you apply to something use **"Apply To …"**.

Be careful with terms like **"Share Your Comment"**, as it has to be commonly understood what sharing means on your site (think of Facebook and the consequences it has when you “share” something). Same counts for something like **"Send Your Feedback"**, because is it send to the server or by email and to who, and is this information really necessary? Keep it clear and simple.

Answer (score 0):

The ideal one is **Post** or **Share**.

Commit refers to a Final change which one can rollback to as a Checkpoint.

Apply refers to a change they have recently made.

Send is often used in Messaging.

Okay is  an affirmative action but doesn't convey what is going to happen unless you ask a question before.

**Posting a comment** makes most sense. But since it's a community, it's also sensible to **Share your thoughts** as a Comment.